# Prestashop : SmartyException' with message 'unable to write file...'

Tags: permissions, smarty, prestashop

I know this subject has already been covered, and if I come to ask for help here, it's because all the solutions I've found on the Internet didn't work for me.

The problem is the following :

I'm using Prestashop 1.6. I developed my website locally and everything worked just fine, so I decided to put it online. But after moving the database and the website on my FTP, I am encountering the following error :

> > > Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'unable to write file /home/web/chienchat/cache/smarty/compile/wrt53fc8900660ea3.68556794' in /home/web/chienchat/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php:44 
> > >       Stack trace:#0 /home/web/chienchat/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(201): Smarty_Internal_Write_File::writeFile('/home/web/chien...', 'compileTemplateSource() #2 /home/web/chienchat/classes/module/Module.php(1860): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch()#3 /home/web/chienchat/modules/blockuserinfo/blockuserinfo.php(72): ModuleCore->display('/home/web/chien...', 'blockuserinfo.t...')#4 /home/web/chienchat/classes/Hook.php(507): BlockUserInfo->hookDisplayTop(Array) #5 /home/web/chienchat/classes/controller/FrontController.php(444): HookCore::exec('displayTop') #6 /home/web/chienchat/controllers/front/IndexController.php(37): F in /home/web/chienchat/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 44

I found it could be the file permissions, so for the sake of testing I've set CHMOD 777 on the whole www, by using FileZilla. The problem is still here.
 I would like to point out that after deleting the cache/smarty folder, and after refreshing the non-working page, the folder cache/smarty/compile is anew created, but it is empty. Please help me, I can't seem to approach any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The correct permission is 755. If this does not work try with 775.

Also the apache user must be the owner of the required folders.

The folders are listed here:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Installing+PrestaShop#InstallingPrestaShop-Systemcompatibility

Comment: I didn't install a new Prestashop, I transfered my local prestashop folder to my website. Do I need to reinstall Prestashop directly? By the way, how can I be certain that the apache user I'm on is the owner of the required folders ? I created them in my ftp, and I used the "root" user to login to the server, so I'm pretty sure it's fine, isn't it? How can I get the environment compatiblity check without going through the installation again ? I am very thankful for your concern. 
I precise I am not using linux or ubuntu and thus I can't type command lines like I see on most internet topics.

Comment: No, you do not need to reinstall PrestaShop. Just make sure that the folders have permissions. In most cases this is the problem - smarty can't write in the compile folder (cache/smarty/compile). You can check it at BackOffice > Advanced Parameters > Configuration Information. The root user and the apache user are two different users. Root has access, but apache may have not. Just test with 755 to the cache/smarty/compile.

Comment: I have set CHMOD 755 on every folder and file, it didn't work. I tried with 775, it didn't work either. I cannot access the back-office on the server so I can't check the configuration information. What can I do? I got a new information : I deleted again the cache/smarty folder, but when I refreshed the page, the folder wasn't created again. After putting CHMOD 777 on the "cache" folder, and after refreshing again the page, the folder cache/smarty and cache/smarty/compile were created, but the latter is empty.

Comment: 1. Find which is your apache user 2. Make it the owner of the whole distribution, recursively

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but how can I do that without going through command lines ? I feel my explanations are not complete so I'm gonna add that it is a test server hosted by www.nerim.fr, and I've never used this host before. There are several test websites hosted on the server, but I've never used an apache server before so I just put my website where I was told to in the FTP directory. I then transfered the database and  I'm stopped by this error, I didn't do anything regarding the server that was already there. However there are several virtual servers hosted for the other websites.

Comment: How can I find which is the apache user 2 and how to set it the owner of the distribution please?

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur if you use the filesystem cache. Many of the prestashop plugins are written in a way that causes a cache miss and store for lots of combinations of each page (page name, category name, language etc.) If you have a large number of products this can mean that you run over the Inode limit for the cache folder and you'll start to see this error, but only on first time visits to pages. Pages that were already in the cache will still render properly.

The solutions in this case are to

a) clear the cache
b) fix all the cache ids for every module
c) use an alternative caching strategy

A warning for c however - it doesn't fix the problem as the cache is still growing. It just takes away the filesystem limits on how many cache items you can hold. The best I can suggest for those suffering this problem is to automatically tail the log and clear the cache when this error occurs.